# Using pandas to join specific elements from three separate CSV files into one CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have the following three CSV files:

```
1.csv:
id,status,env
aaaa,PASS,PROD
aaaa,PASS,DEV
bbbb,PASS,PROD
bbbb,PASS,DEV

2.csv:
id,successPct24,env
aaaa,"99.73",PROD
aaaa,"99.89",DEV
bbbb,"100.00",PROD
bbbb,"92.53",DEV

3.csv
id,successPctMonth,env
aaaa,"99.70",PROD
aaaa,"99.90",DEV
bbbb,"100.00",PROD
bbbb,"99.91",DEV
```

The goal is to create a single CSV file formatted as follows:

```
id,status,successPct24,successPctMonth,env
```

So, using my example CSV files, the single CSV should look like this:

```
aaaa,PASS,99.73,99.7,PROD
aaaa,PASS,99.89,99.9,DEV
bbbb,PASS,100.0,100.0,PROD
bbbb,PASS,92.53,99.91,DEV
```

I've attempted to use the following Python code to accomplish this...

```
import pandas as pd

csv1 = pd.read_csv("1.csv", index_col=[0], usecols=["id", "status"])

csv2 = pd.read_csv("2.csv", index_col=[0], usecols=["id", "successPct24"])

csv3 = pd.read_csv("3.csv", index_col=[0], usecols=["id", "successPctMonth", "env"])

firstcsv = csv1.join(csv2)

finalcsv = firstcsv.join(csv3)

# print (finalcsv)

finalcsv.to_csv('4.csv', index=True)
```

...but the resulting single CSV is not correct:

```
aaaa,PASS,99.73,99.7,PROD
aaaa,PASS,99.73,99.9,DEV
aaaa,PASS,99.89,99.7,PROD
aaaa,PASS,99.89,99.9,DEV
aaaa,PASS,99.73,99.7,PROD
aaaa,PASS,99.73,99.9,DEV
aaaa,PASS,99.89,99.7,PROD
aaaa,PASS,99.89,99.9,DEV
bbbb,PASS,100.0,100.0,PROD
bbbb,PASS,100.0,99.91,DEV
bbbb,PASS,92.53,100.0,PROD
bbbb,PASS,92.53,99.91,DEV
bbbb,PASS,100.0,100.0,PROD
bbbb,PASS,100.0,99.91,DEV
bbbb,PASS,92.53,100.0,PROD
bbbb,PASS,92.53,99.91,DEV
```

I'm sure there's a parameter I'm missing, or something I've misconfigured. Any assistance with this request would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is missing/incorrect in the final csv?

Comment: Oops...forgot to include that. Just edited my post to reflect the incorrect CSV data I'm seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to join by 2 columns - `'id' and 'env'`
Code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("2.csv")
df3 = pd.read_csv("3.csv")
finalcsv = df1.merge(df2, 'left', on=['id', 'env']).merge(df3, 'left', on=['id', 'env'])
```

Result:

```
    id      status  env     successPct24    successPctMonth
0   aaaa    PASS    PROD    99.73           99.70
1   aaaa    PASS    DEV     99.89           99.90
2   bbbb    PASS    PROD    100.00          100.00
3   bbbb    PASS    DEV     92.53           99.91
```

If you need another order of columns:

```
finalcsv = finalcsv[['id', 'status', 'successPct24', 'successPctMonth', 'env']]
```

Comment: This did the trick...thank you! I had to add a line from @jcaliz answer to remove the "0,1,2,3" from my output.

Comment: i'm not using columns as index in this code, so to remove default index values (0,1,2,3) from csv you just need to write `index=False` in to_csv:  `finalcsv.to_csv('4.csv', index=False)`

Answer (score 2):

`join` function always uses indexes to perform the join, and you have multiple records sharing the same index, if you need to join using more columns then use `merge`.

Frist solution is just to assign the columns, but this is only if they are in the same order:

```
temp = csv1.copy() 
temp['successPct24'] = csv2['successPct24']
temp['successPctMonth'] = csv3['successPctMonth']
temp['env'] = csv3['env']

print(temp)
```

The second solution is to use `merge` but the index itself is not sufficient so you need to use the `env` column:

```
csv1 = pd.read_csv("1.csv", usecols=["id", "status", "env"])
csv2 = pd.read_csv("2.csv", usecols=["id", "successPct24", "env"])
csv3 = pd.read_csv("3.csv", usecols=["id", "successPctMonth", "env"])

firstcsv = csv1.merge(csv2, left_on=["id", "env"], right_on=["id", "env"])
finalcsv = firstcsv.merge(csv3,  left_on=["id", "env"], right_on=["id", "env"])

finalcsv.set_index('id', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you! I had implemented the solution that @dmitriy-k provided before yours, but I had to use your "finalcsv.set_index" line to fix the output.

Comment: I think mine was first, but that doesn't matter the important is that you got it.